# How do you read dot notation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, notation

For the sake of an example, is this statement

```
window.Number.constructor.prototype.constructor();
```

read like a path?

```
C:\Users\Vista\Documents\Work\text.txt
```

From left to right

```
window:\Number\constructor\prototype\constructor()
```

where `window` is the root object, `Number` is an object inside `window`, `constructor` is an object inside `Number`, `prototype` is an object inside `constructor` and `constructor()` is an object inside `prototype`?

Just like in this statement

```
window.document.myForm.textBox.value;
```

which equals

```
[object].[object].[object].[object].1
```

where the objects aren't actually acting on each other?

**OR**

Are the actual values read from right to left, where each object is acting on the object directly to the left of it?

Where

```
window.Number.constructor.prototype.constructor();
```

equals

```
[object] . function Number() { [native code] } . function Function() { [native code] } . function prototype() { [native code] } . function anonymous() { }
```

as

```
window.Number(9.256).toFixed(2);
```

equals

```
[object].(9.256).(9.26);
```

where `toFixed` is a property that's using the return value of the `Number` object and the result is stored as a property of the `window` object?

As you can probably tell, I'm kinda tangled up over here :) Just having difficulty wrapping my head around the dot concept. I'm sure a background in Java would help, but unfortunately, I don't have one (yet).

Comment: What do you have a background in?

Comment: Javascript and java has nothing to do with each other. It was called livescript until it was added to the Netscape browser about the same time as java was added. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript And look at the answer by Charlie Martin to thet the answer of your question. Good luck!

Comment: Joe, my background is mainly in web design, but I'm hoping to move more into a developer role in the near future. some, thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 3):

Read from left to right.  Each "thing" resolves to an object.  Objects can have properties or functions.  A property is another object, which can in turn have its own properties and functions.  If it is a function, then to be legal syntax the function must return an object.  Then the chained item to the right must be a property (or function) of that object.

A framework like jQuery works by having each of it's methods return a copy of itself so that methods can be chained together.

In your first example it is referring to a chain of object properties, except the last one which is a function.  In the second, it invokes a function on the window object, which returns a Number object that has a toFixed() function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, or like a field in a `struct` in C.  It's actually a bunch of hash tables or dictionaries.  So your example

```
window.Number.constructor.prototype.constructor()
```

Is "The window object, an item named 'Number', which contains an item named 'constructor', which contains an item named 'prototype' --- which is where the methods are named --- which contains a method named constructor."  That final `()` means "and treat this as a function with no arguments."

Answer (score 0):

Left to right.